# Debug only specific query in magento

Tags: debug, query

I want to log all the query that affect only specific table. For example `catalog_product_flat_1`. So if query makes update, delete or insert operation to this table it should be logged. It cаused by deleting column `sku` from time to time from this table and I want to find out the reason.

Answer (score 3):

Enable logging by

1. setting `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::_logAllQueries` to `true`
2. setting `\Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::$_debug` to `true`

Then grep in the file `var/debug/pdo_mysql.log` for the table name. You can also add code to `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::_debugStat` which filters for the table name.